# neo4j and neovis cannot visualize on Azure web service

Tags: javascript, neo4j, neovis

I make a neo4j server on azure virtual machine.
I use neovis to develop my app.
[image]
It is working fine on localhost (pictured above)
but when published to Azure web service it doesn't show my graph
I get the following error by web console
[image]

this is my neovis config. This problem keeps making me puzzled. How can i solve this problem?

```
var config = {
  server_url: "bolt://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:7687",
  container_id: "viz",
  server_user: "neo4j",
  server_password: "password",
  arrows: true,
  labels: {
    "Troll": {
      "caption": "name",
      "title_properties": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  },
  relationships: {
    "RETWEETS": {
      "caption": false
    }
  },
  initial_cypher: cypher_script
};
viz = new NeoVis.default(config);  
viz.render();
console.log(viz);
```